# Minecraft: How to easily create (in-game) maps in creative

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

*Note: the word **map** in this question refers to the maps you can create in game from the world, not to the world itself.*

On my minecraft server running in creative mode, we just started to create a map-wall of our world in 1:2 scale. This means:

1. get a new map
2. go to the area of which you need a map
3. open the map to initialize it
4. use a crafting table to extend the map to factor 1:2
5. move around to fill the map
6. repeat until you have all maps you need
7. place all maps onto frames on a wall to get a large, seamless map of the world

Though I guess you can't avoid to move around to fill a map, steps 3 an 4 are a bit annoying.
So, is there any way to speed this up? For instance a command which gives an uninitialized map with 1:2 factor directly?

Comment: There's probably a plugin or mod to help you with this.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/349049-map-help).

You might want to use this command:

```
/give @p minecraft:filled_map 1 0 {scale:2,xCenter:0,zCenter:0}


/give @p minecraft:filled_map [amount] [map number] {scale:[scale],xCenter:[x],zCenter:[y]}
```

For `[map number]`, enter the next available map number. Look in your world's `/data/` folder for `map_0.dat` The highest number plus one is what you want to enter. If you have never created a map, enter `0`. Make sure you always add `1` after using the command.

You can find your world folder by clicking on your world then pressing `Edit`, then clicking the button that says something like "Open world folder" (1.11)

<sup>Most info retrieved from Versepelles on Minecraft Forums.</sup>

Comment: If any of this is directly quoted, you need to use the quote markdown to give credit.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/give @p filled_map{...}`

Comment: and of COURSE this won't work on Bedrock edition, because being new and improved it doesn't support passing that extra data to the command :'-(

Answer (score 0):

To skip all the steps is impossible at the moment, but to skip steps 3-4 is possible!

To do this you will need this command:

```
/give [playername] minecraft:filled_map [amount of maps] [number of map]
```

This will give the player(/give) a map that is filled.  Put in the number of maps you want and then the scaling you want.

This is a discussion on this topic: http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/2085120-how-do-you-give-a-player-a-specific-map-using

Comment: Sorry, this is not the solution I'm looking for. The `number of map` is just a counter which is increased whenever you create a map for a given region / ratio for the very first time. It's also used in the file name containing the map data:`<worlddir>/data/map_12.dat`. This number gives just the order of creation and is not related to section/ratio. So your command allows to get a map already created before and is only useful if you know by heart which card number you need...

Comment: Just to be more clear: Go somewhere on the map and open an empty map. It will become filled_map #0. Go somewhere else, make a new filed_map, and it will be #1. Go back to the first location, and resize that map #0. The new map is #2. Create a new map again there, and it will again be #0. If the world has changed and you explore it with you second #0 map, changes will be merged into the first #0 map, too.

Answer (score 0):

How to do it in Minecraft PE:
1: Collect an empty map from the 'seeds' tab.
2: Create an empty space in your hotbar.
3: Hold your empty map.
4: Press 'Create Map'
5: Go into first person view to see the map.
6: Go and explore!

Comment: That's not the point. The question is if it is possible to get the map without exploring, and, more important, get one with lower zoom level without stitching four maps together.